# Variable transformation $Y= \sin (X)$ where $X$ is uniform on $[0, \pi]$

Tags: probability-theory

Given $X$ is uniform on $[0, \pi]$.

Let $Y= \sin (X)$ then $y \in [0,1].$

What is the distribution of Y? If intuition serves me correct I would think that Y is uniform on $[0, 1]$. But when I start to do the variable transformation I get stuck.

$P(Y \le y) = P(\sin (X) \le y) = P(X \le \arcsin(y) = \frac{arcsin(y)}{\pi}$ for $y \in [0,1].$

Then $ \arcsin(y)$ would take on two values for each $y$ value and this is where I am stuck.

Comment: Related: "arcsine distribution" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcsine_distribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there.  Because, as you noticed, almost every point on the support of $Y$ maps to two points on the support of $X$, we must consider both those contributions.

If we take $\;\color{navy}{\arcsin : [-1;1]\mapsto [-\pi/2; \pi/2]}$ , then the cumulative distribution function of $Y$ is:

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(0\leq Y\leq y) & = \mathsf P\Big(\big(0\leq X \leq \arcsin(y)\big) \cup \big(\pi-\arcsin(y)\leq X\leq \pi\big)\Big)
\\ & = \frac{\arcsin(y)+(\pi-\pi+\arcsin(y))}{\pi} \mathsf 1_{[0;1)}(y)+\mathsf 1_{[1;\infty)}(y)
\\ & = \frac{2\arcsin(y)}{\pi} \mathsf 1_{[0;1)}(y)+\mathsf 1_{[1;\infty)}(y)
\end{align}$$

Because if we [plot $y=\sin(x)$ for $x\in[0;\pi]$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%7C+sin%28x%29+%7C+x+%3D+0+to+pi) then we notice that there are two intervals on the support of $X$ where $Y\leq y$.   These correspond to the intervals $X\in [0;\arcsin(y)]$ and $X\in [\pi-\arcsin(y);\pi]$.

Now, can you find the probability density function?  (Note: This is not uniformly distributed.)

Comment: But why can we freely change the domain of Y? I thought that it is restricted to the input we give it $[0,1]$ that's where I'm confused about for variable transformation, I don't know how to find the domain of the new transformed variable.

Comment: The support of $Y$ *is* $[0;1]$, but *two* intervals of the support of $X$ both map to this.  That is $[0;\pi/2]$ and $(\pi/2; \pi]$.  @YellowPillow

Comment: Then why would we take arcsin : [-1 ; 1], would it not be [0 ; 1]?

Answer (score 1):

Confused? Draw the graph of $\sin x$, for $0\leq x\leq\pi$. Is it one-to-one? If the answer is no, then you have to tread carefully.  Draw a horizontal line at a fixed $y$ and look for all the $x$ values in $[0,\pi]$ that satisfy your inequality $\sin(x)\leq y$.  You'll realize they don't form an interval, but the union of two disjoint intervals (symmetric with respect to $x=\pi/2$), unless $y=1$.

Still confused? Learn about Iverson brackets (and thank Don Knuth).